# After Transposing 1d matrix it prints garbage

Tags: matrix, transpose

I have created a 1d array inside a matrix class. It prints fine. But when I transpose it and print afterwards it prints gibberish. I have checked the swapped values, they are also the way they should be. But when I print it it prints garbage. Here is the output after transposing it:

```
-572662307 -572662307 -572662307
-572662307 -572662307 -572662307
-572662307 -572662307 -572662307
-572662307 -572662307 -572662307
-572662307 -572662307 -572662307
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

```
inside Matrix Transpose.h file: 

class Matrix{
   public:
       int* array;
       int row, column;
       std::bitset<HASH_SIZE> b;
       Matrix(int r, int c) : row(r), column(c), array(new int[r * c]) {}
       ~Matrix() { delete[] array;}
       int size() { return row * column; }
       void inputMatrix();
       void PrintArray();
};  

void MatrixInplaceTranspose(Matrix matrix);

inside Matrix Transpose.cpp file:

void MatrixInplaceTranspose(Matrix matrix){
int r = matrix.row, c = matrix.column;
int size = r * c - 1;
int temp; 
int next; 
int cycleBegin; 
int i; 
matrix.b.reset();
matrix.b[0] = matrix.b[size] = 1;
i = 1; 
while (i < size)
{
    cycleBegin = i;
    temp = matrix.array[i];
    do
    {
        next = (i * r) % size;
        swap(matrix.array[next], temp); 
        matrix.b[i] = 1;
        i = next;
    } while (i != cycleBegin);

    for (i = 1; i < size && matrix.b[i]; i++)
        ;
    cout << endl;
}}

inside main.cpp:

using namespace std;
void Matrix::inputMatrix(){
   for (int i = 0; i < this->size(); i++)
       array[i] = i + 1;

}

void Matrix::PrintArray(){
   for (int r = 0; r < this->row; r++)  {
      for (int c = 0; c < this->column; c++)
        cout << this->array[r*this->column + c] << " "; 
      cout<<"\n";
}

cout<<"\n\n";}


int main(void){
Matrix First(2, 5), Second(5, 3);
First.PrintArray();
Second.PrintArray();
MatrixInplaceTranspose(Second);
Second.PrintArray();
cin.get();
return 0;
```

}